# Server-Sent Events in native app?

Tags: android, server-sent-events

Is there any way I can use [server-sent events](http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/) in a native Android app?

Answer (score 2):

You can, but you'll have to implement the parsing, reconnecting, and other parts of the spec yourself.

This isn't too onerous; you'll need to build on top of an http library that lets you process bytes as they come in over the wire.  I've built a [Python library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sseclient/) that parses SSE streams, and is build on [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).  You should be able to write something similar in Java.

Comment: If an application has to be constantly listening to receive SSE, this is not possible on Android. You have to use FCM instead. A python app can freely run forever, but an Android app will be terminated after a while, if it is no longer shown to the user (in the foreground). I guess this was previously possible (in 2012, when you wrote this answer), as services were less restricted.